# Changing Youtube Iframe playerVars dynamically

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, youtube-api

I have a webpage that uses the Youtube Iframe API and I managed to change the videoId using this line of code:

```
player.loadVideoById(videoId)
```

But in order for the video to loop both videoId and playlist have to match and so I also need to change the playlist parameter inside the playerVars object. Could someone tell me an easy way to approach this?

This is the original code:

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('player', {
height: '390',
width: '640',
videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
playerVars: { 
    'loop' : 1,
    'playlist': 'M7lc1UVf-VE'
    },
events: {
  'onReady': onPlayerReady,
  'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
 });
}
```

I have tried setting a variable as shown below and changed it dynamically as I did loadVideoById:

```
player.loadVideoById(videoId) 
currentVideoId = videoId
```

and

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('player', {
height: '390',
width: '640',
videoId: currentVideoId,
playerVars: { 
    'loop' : 1,
    'playlist': currentVideoId
    },
events: {
  'onReady': onPlayerReady,
  'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [.loadPlaylist()](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#loadPlaylist) to specify the playlist and the (numerical) *index* of the video (within the playlist) instead of the video id.

```
player.loadPlaylist({list:String,
                 listType:String,
                 index:Number,
                 startSeconds:Number,
                 suggestedQuality:String}):Void
```

> This function loads the specified list and plays it. The list can be a playlist, a search results feed, or a user's uploaded videos feed.
>
> - The optional **`listType`** property specifies the type of results feed that you are retrieving. Valid values are **`playlist`**, **`search`**, and **`user_uploads`**. The default value is **`playlist`**.
> - The required **`list`** property contains a key that identifies the particular list of videos that YouTube should return.
>
> ...
>
> <sup>[1](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#loadPlaylist)</sup>

See [this example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfsa8b30/1/) where two videos in two different playlists are loaded in the `clickEventHandler()` function (depending on the *id* attribute value of the list item clicked).

```
player.loadPlaylist({
    list: 'PLUdAMlZtaV11U9AtszkMh0bpRqM4dtlDC',
    index: 7
  });
```